# deallocating array of pointer in fortran

Tags: fortran90

I am new to Fortran. I am facing a problem with array of pointers. I am writing code in Fortran90. Due to large size of data I have to use array of pointers. Pseudocode is like this

```
type  ::a
   integer   ::Id
   real       ::Coords(3)
end type a
type ::b
    type(a),pointer   ::Member 
end type b
type(b),allocatable   ::data(:)
integer               ::i
!allocation and assigning
allocate(data(n))
do i=1,n
    allocate(d(i)%member)
    d(i)%member%Id = i
    d(i)%member%Coordinates(:) = i*2.0
end do

!Some stuff using data

!De allocation
do i=1,n
    deallocate(d(i)%member)
end do
deallocate(data)
```

I have observed that deallocating the array of pointers in this way is very slow. When dealing with some milions of datasets, it takes significant time to do this. and if I don't do this, the memory doesn't gets released. I want to reuse the data by assigning with new size (new n value in pseudocode) without exiting the program. So I can't run away without deallocating the array, otherwise there will not be enough memory available for doing next stuffs.

Can anyone suggest me if there could be some other way of deallocating array of pointers in Fortran? or can I handle large dataset in my Fortran program?

Thanks

Comment: How long is "significant time," because I ran your code (modified to fix the typos) and it took, using gfortran 4.7.2, about 0.5 seconds to fill `d` (or `data`) and about 0.2 seconds to `deallocate` it all (using `cpu_time` for testing) with `n=10000000`.

Comment: Why is the `Member` component of type `b` a pointer?  From the code you show it doesn't have to be.

Comment: Are you allocating and deallocating every time you enter the routine?

Comment: Why is there even a `type b`? Why not make `data` an array (pointers or not) of `type a`??